# Can a wave be sent on the string at the speed of light

Tags: relativity

I just learned about relativity in my basic physics class. In thinking about the mathematical consequence of the Lorentz equations that nothing can travel faster than the speed of light(for that would result in a mathematical impossibility) I came to the following thought experiment. Imagine I were to take a very low density string and apply a very high tension to it. I could produce a wave which travels at an arbitrary speed. It seems to me then that the speed of propagation of this mechanical wave can exceed the speed of light.

Please verify or refute this assertion.

Comment: Before someone answers, can you guess whether this is a relativity loophole or not?

Comment: At minimum you should explain why you think this would work. (It won't, but it's not even clear why you think that it should.)

Comment: why could you apply arbitrary tensions to strings without breaking them?

Comment: I don't have the knowledge to justify why I don't think this will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The max wave propagation speed in a plucked wire is of order ~the velocity of sound waves in the wire (~thousands of feet per second). This is far, far slower than the speed of light. Tightening the wire to increase the speed of propagation will break the wire long before you could possibly get anywhere near the speed of light.

This is an old question in the sense that ever since Maxwell demonstrated that you could calculate the speed of light from his equations, people have been drawing analogies between the speed of light in a vacuum and the speed of sound in some arbitrary medium and then back-calculating the stiffness and mass density in that medium which is required to get its sonic velocity to equal the speed of light. This requires a medium which is impossibly stiff and light.